# After splitting data ,date is printing like object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

```
for i in range(1,dset.shape[0]):
    dat=datetime.strptime(dset[i,0],'%Y%m%d').date()
    date.append(dat)
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test,ydates_train,ydates_test=train_test_split(data,Y,date,test_size=0.2)
```

After I split dates, Then I print or plot date it behaves like an object (Ex. `Datetime.datetime(2001,11,11)` )

where as before split it prints in `DateTime` format (ex-`2001/11/11`).

Comment: That's to be expected - you're converting it to a datetime/date object. If you're doing that to just reformat it and it's a string in YYYY/MM/DD format... can't you just replace the `/` with an empty string instead?

Comment: @JonClements dates are in string format in my dataset. Due to this I am not able to split data using pandas test_train_split. Please elaborate what can be other way